# why does Google Analytics show different top content results for URL and Page Title?

Tags: google-analytics

in GA content>AllPages the default view shows the top pageviews by URL. Since my site does not have friendly URLs I prefer to view by page title, but when I click to change the view instead of showing the same pages by top pageviews it shows completely different pages. 
I want it to simply switch to the title of the same pages instead of the URL, why would the top pageviews be different based on URL and title?

Comment: Do you have duplicate page titles?

Comment: no, it is showing a completely different list of pages when I switch from URL to titles along with different pageview numbers

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be showing title as second dimension, and url as first. You can find out if you have duplicate titles too this way.

With default GA settings, you cannot do this. However, there is an hack how to do this: from Content->Site Content->All Pages, add a second dimension (Source for example). Then go and edit the url bar, and instead of source (last word) add pageTitle.

For example:

```
www.google.com/analytics/web/ (some more stuff) table.secSegmentId%3Danalytics.source/
```

To

```
www.google.com/analytics/web/ (some more stuff) table.secSegmentId%3Danalytics.pageTitle/
```

this should do it

Comment: I'll try that, but I guess I'm more curious as to why the content report functions this way. Wouldn't you expect to see the same pages but instead by title as I described? Duplicate titles is not my problem.

Comment: It's probably a situation related with the nature of your website, difficult to tell without seeing the data. A thing that I have noticed is that the stats reflect the title that is actually displayed on the user's browser, so if they use google translate, it will appear a title in a foreign language on your stats (screwing the type of stats you wanted to see)